# select smallest difference between dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I  get the difference between two date columns and return the top 5 smallest differences between these two dates using tSQL? I want this down to the minute if possible.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and the expected output. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT TOP 5 date1, date2, DATEDIFF(minute, date1, date2)
 FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY DATEDIFF(minute, date1, date2)
```

Comment: Might want to put an ABS() function around the datediff in case date1 isn't always the earlier one.